# Style tag in text Input causes crash

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I cant get this code to work in XML. Inside the CardView i want a text Input with the Outlined Box style but the app dose not open in the emulator. Here is the working code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:textColor="#303A43"
                    android:textColorHint="#7A8089"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This code works and gives an ugly Text Input Field but when i put;

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

in the TextInputLayout Or after Line 34, The app does not open in the emulator and i get an error "App Keeps Stopping"

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it in TextInputLayout

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```